# Change nickname in XMPP chat room using quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox, xmppframework

I'm working on a group chat using quickblox. I want to change nickname in a chat room but unable to achieve this. I'm trying below code:

```
[xmppRoom changeNickname:roomNickName];
```

It says "You have insufficient privileges"

Comment: First you need to give permission of "participants allow to change nickname" while creating room.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna: Which API would do that in quickblox? I tried to do it from admin dashboard but no luck.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way you are allowed to do this. Quickblox using user ID as roomNick in order to keep tracking and allow users to join and you can only set it before room join.